# Python script leaves command line stuck

Tags: python, shell

I wrote a Python script to let me call previously written functions in other classes directly from the command line. It works fine -- once. But the script seems like it never finishes running, and I can't input anything into command prompt after running it without closing that command prompt window and opening a new one. All my code is below:

```
import yaml
import numpy as np
from robot_move import UR3
import argparse 
import inspect

def moveReactors():
    _, success = rob.waypointMove(store, waypoint)
    if success:
        success = rob.pickplacexyz(store,[0,0,0],disp)
        if success:
            success = rob.pickplace(store,goal)

            return success




#setup variables from the config file            
with open('robot_config.txt') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f) 
IP       = config['IP']
store    = np.array(config['reactorStorePose'])
disp     = np.array(config['reactor1Disp'])
goal     = np.array(config['reactorGoalPose'])
waypoint = np.array(config['reactorWaypointAngles'])

rob = UR3(IP)


# get the names of all the functions to be passed to the parser
selfFuncNames = [name for name in dir() if inspect.isfunction(globals().get(name))]
robFuncNames  = [name for name in dir(rob) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(rob,name)) and not name[0] == '_']

#parse the command line input for functions to be called
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Command the robot")
for funcName in robFuncNames+selfFuncNames:
    parser.add_argument('-'+funcName, nargs = '*')

called    = {funcName:args for funcName, args in vars(parser.parse_args()).items() if not args is None}

# call each function with its arguments
for funcName in called:
    if funcName in robFuncNames:
        func = getattr(rob,funcName)
    elif funcName in selfFuncNames:
        func = globals().get(funcName)

    #funcArgs, funcVarargs, funcKeywords, funcDefaults = inspect.getargspec(func)

    args = called[funcName]
    args = [globals().get(arg) if arg in globals() else arg for arg in args] #let user pass in the names of arguments in this scripts' namespace

    try:
        if len(args) > 0:
            print func(*args)
        else:
            print func()
    except Exception as exc:
        raise Exception ('Command "' + funcName + '" failed: ' +str(exc) )


print ('Success!')
```

Comment: If you want to stop the process, use Ctrl-C in the command line.

Comment: I've tried that, along with ctrl-z and ctrl-\. None have worked.

Comment: First thing would be to find out what happens at Ctrl-C. Does the program terminate and only leave the terminal in a bad state? You can check that with `ps` from another terminal.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more there?